Trigger a custom event from outside of router-view in Vue.js
I'm new to Vue.js and can't seem to get how an event is passed from a component outside of the router-view to App.vue. I'm currently using the below code in the App.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <NavBar :userId="userId" :loggedIn="isLoggedIn" />
        <router-view :userId="userId"
            @user-logged-in="getLoggedInUserInfo" 
            @user-logged-out="getLoggedOutUserInfo">
        </router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from '@/components/NavBar.vue';

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        NavBar,
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
          userId: null,
          isLoggedIn: false,
        }
    },    
    methods: {
        getLoggedInUserInfo: function(data) {
            this.userId = data.user.userId;
            this.isLoggedIn = true;
        },

        getLoggedOutUserInfo: function() {
            this.userId = '';
            this.isLoggedIn = false;
        }
    }
}
</script>

I am using a page(component) Login.vue to enter credentials for logging in to the application. This page is part of the router-view. I can trigger the user-logged-in event from the Login.vue page and it works as expected when a user logs in.
this.$emit("user-logged-in", data);
However, when the user logs out, I want to receive some information in the NavBar component, so that I can re-render the NavBar menu items. The logout button stays in the Navbar component.
I tried to emit the logout to the App.vue from the NavBar.vue as shown and it does not work:
this.$emit("user-logged-out");
Any help is much appreciated!

As per my understanding the logout button is present in the NavBar, but you are listening for the event in router-view, you can simply emit the event from NavBar and handle it like <NavBar :userId="userId" :loggedIn="isLoggedIn" @user-logged-out="getLoggedOutUserInfo">

you don't need any events, since you already have reactive props in NavBar, every change should be propagated through reactive data, events are the last resort

You're trying to solve app-wide problem with local state. Auth is the case for global state, https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html

@YashMaheshwari, thanks a lot for the solution. it worked like a charm

As the logout button is present in the NavBar, but you are listening for the event in router-view, you can simply emit the event from NavBar and handle it App file.
<NavBar :userId="userId" :loggedIn="isLoggedIn" @user-logged-out="getLoggedOutUserInfo">


Above mentioned solution worked for me. Thank you @Yash Maheshwari

i suggest you to make an eventBus
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();

then trigger events from navbar component
and listen to the events using event bus
or
try to use "mitt" from npm and to make eventBus and use it across the application
import mitt from 'mitt'
const emitter = mitt()
export default emitter

Old school but might work. More context (+ SSR): https://deltener.com/blog/nuxt-enterprise-patterns-the-event-bus/

It's supposed to work

The question suggests it's Vue 3. There's no "new Vue" there.

try to use "mitt" from npm and use it across the application

Event bus is a anti pattern.
